# How can I add inputs (textbox, slider etc.) into autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

We can move objects using the [transform tool](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension). I want to display the current x, y, z coordinates of the selected object in an input and change it from there. But I couldn't add any input. I found [examples](http://sample-collection.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) but could not find source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the inputs I want in html. And inside the motion function, I updated them dynamically over the value received by them.

```
<!--TRANSFORM DIV- index.html-->
<div id="MyControls" class="adsk control">
    <label>X</label>
    <input id="XAxis" type="text" />
    <label>Y</label>
    <input id="YAxis" type="text" />
    <label>Z</label>
    <input id="ZAxis" type="text" />
</div>


// transform.js
 var AxisArray = ["XAxis", "YAxis", "ZAxis"];

    AxisArray.forEach(function (axis) {
        document.getElementById(axis).addEventListener("change", function () {
            positionChangeInputs();
        });
    });


    function positionChangeInputs() {
        
        for (var fragId in _selectedFragProxyMap) {

            var fragProxy = _selectedFragProxyMap[fragId];

            var position = new THREE.Vector3(
                fragProxy.position.x = document.getElementById("XAxis").value,
                fragProxy.position.y = document.getElementById("YAxis").value,
                fragProxy.position.z = document.getElementById("ZAxis").value);

            fragProxy.position = position;

            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
        }

        viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
       
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/MyForgeBlogs/tree/master/02.ViewerObjectRotation).

It's a part of my colleague's blog about [creating component transformations in forge viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics).

Comment: I've seen this before. There is no UI part here. Dynamically changing the position information of a selected object that I am trying to do via any input